# How to configure multisite on Linux with Apache + Apache + Discourse

Tags: web-server, apache-2.4, multiple-instances

## Situation and problem

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04 VPS, and want to host multiple sites on it, all with distinct domains:

- A wordpress installation (PHP + MySQL)
- A simple PHP site, no database
- A [Discourse](http://discourse.org) installation. Discourse is based on Ruby on Rails

Each site has a distinct domain name. When I search for multisite setups, I mostly find guides to *specific* servers, for instance [how to setup multiple Discourse forums on a single server](https://meta.discourse.org/t/multisite-configuration-with-docker/14084). I have a feeling this is really a common problem, I'm just asking the wrong question.

My current understanding of the problem is that

- A domain points to a single IP address
- A server can listen on a single port
- A server can retrieve the domain name from the request header

## Solution?

This leads me to the impression that a solution could be

1. A thin server listening on :80 and :8080 looks up domain name and delegates the request
2. Each site runs on the server listening on other ports, and delivers the required site

Intuitively this seems like a basic problem

## Questions

- Am I on the right track?
- Are there lighter alternatives to Apache for the delegation?

Comment: A solution that allows hosting other web servers in addition to the Discourse installation is using a [layered NGINX setup](https://meta.discourse.org/t/running-other-websites-on-the-same-machine-as-discourse/17247).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the current description I do not see why a standard virtual host setup in Apache (or indeed whatever your favourite HTTP server is) would not work.

Start by reading about name based virtual hosts here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html which should give you the "three hosts with distinct domains" part.

The execution of PHP and ruby can be configured on a virtual host basis, but the exact configuration will be installation and application dependant.